# run a jquery string command

Tags: jquery, string, command, execute

I have a string that contains a jquery command
How can I execute this string?

```
var myCommand = "$('#update').html('hello world!');";
```

Comment: Why do you have a string that has JavaScript code in it?  Where is it coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not try to execute command from string, if you need to reuse them you should use a function:

```
var myCommand = function(){
    $('#update').html('hello world!');
}
```

and then call it

```
myCommand();
```

Otherwise you must use eval() but it's not a best practice.

Or you could use [globalEval()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.globalEval/) which is better since it doesn't use eval()

Answer (score 0):

```
var myCommand = function(){
    $('#update').html('hello world!');
}
$(function()
{ myCommand();
});
```